# Last Update field in Django... 'auto_now' or 'hidden' widget

Tags: django, datetime

I would like to set a field in a Django model which should be updated everytime a record of the corresponding table is updated by a ModelForm (any field of the table).
I am wondering which of the following options is the best practices one:

- Add the "auto_now" argument to the model field.
- Include the 'type': 'hidden' attribute to the corresponding widget in the form where the records will be submitted. If this... how should be included the 'value' attribute for the widget?

I know the auto_now argument updates the field only when Model.save() is called. So the question could be rebuilt as... Is the Model.save() called when a ModelForm (linked to the model) is submitted?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**auto_now** Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.

So to save updated record time auto_now is the best option

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will create and modify records by Forms submitting, and I hope it works.